# Git Add and Commit of chosen files

Tags: git, github

I have made around 30 file changes in the whole project for testing purposes with debug statements and some variables. Now my code is working according to my requirement.

My code changes are only in 3 files. I have done the below commands to push to my branch

```
 1.  git status 
 2.  git add .
 3.  git commit -m "Commited file changes"
 4.  git push origin MyBranch (This push is to a sub branch development of Master Branch)
```

Now when I look into the GitHub repository there are these 30 files which can be seen in the pull request.

I want only 3 files to be committed. The other 27 files I have removed my earlier debug changes and they are same as in master. How do I do commit only 3 files.

I have tried

```
 git add file1 file2 files3
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Try `git add . -p` next time. It gives you more control to selectively choose what you stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first reset your index to the state *before* your last commit (the last commit which included 30 files instead of only 3)

```
git reset @~
```

(`@` is for HEAD, `~` is for the first parent commit)

Then you can try again

```
git add file1 file2 files3  
git commit -m "commit only 3 files"
```

And you need to force push, that will update the PR, and override its history with that new commit:

```
git push --force -u origin myBranch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try below steps, it will work:

```
1.  git status 
2.  git add file1
3.  git add file2
4.  git add file3
5.  git commit -m "Commited file changes"
6.  git push origin MyBranch or master
```

By adding files one by one will give you less chances to fail.

Comment: Why would this work? Just saying *do this* isn't an answer. Explain why the poster should follow these instructions, so that there is some knowledge passed to future readers.